# Differences Between EntityTypeConfiguration & EntityConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What are the differences between `EntityTypeConfiguration` and `EntityConfiguration`. Both are for entities configurations and mapping. So Where is the differences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no conceptual difference between these classes. EntityConfiguration class was reworked and renamed to EntityTypeConfiguration in EF4.1.